WordPress site returns HTTP 500 because of exception in TranslatePress trp-ajax.php
I'm working on bilingual website and for one of supported languages server throws HTTP 500 with following record in Nginx log:
2024/05/03 11:55:49 [error] 3493#3493: *16346 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given in /var/www/DOMAIN/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/includes/trp-ajax.php:153
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/DOMAIN/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/includes/trp-ajax.php(153): implode()
#1 /var/www/DOMAIN/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/includes/trp-ajax.php(36): TRP_Ajax->output_translations()
#2 /var/www/DOMAIN/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/includes/trp-ajax.php(186): TRP_Ajax->__construct()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/DOMAIN/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/includes/trp-ajax.php on line 153" while reading response header from upstream, client: 141.136.91.90, server: DOMAIN, request: "POST /wp-content/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/includes/trp-ajax.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "DOMAIN", referrer: "https://DOMAIN/ru/cart/"

I've found similar issue described in https://wordpress.org/support/topic/trp-ajax-php-returns-500/, but the tip from there does not help.
Could anybody help with it? I suspect some string translation missing, but need to find out how to debug to proof it.

Since it's part of a third party plugin, you might need to contact the developers of the plugin for suggestions. Any changes you might make to the plugin itself could be overwritten the next time you update the plugin.

Resolved, the issue was in wrong translation string - #% instead of correct one #%s, this led to exception.
